# Dynamically renamed files in bash?

Tags: bash, postgresql, dynamic, filenames

I'm using PostgreSQL script to create a CSV data file using the COPY TO command.
I need to have a new name on the output file every time the script executes. 
But PostgreSQL won't let me use dynamic filenames. It's a security feature.

If I want to `COPY ... TO '\home\yerleth\mydata' || current_date || '.csv'`, I can't.

I was thinking maybe it is possible to set  up some kind of virtual file in bash (like a buffer?)
so that whenever the contents changed, bash would rename the file using my predefined parameters. 
It would be like bash was automatically forwarding the contents into a new file.
That would allow me to use a static filename in the SQL script.
Does this concept exist in bash ?

In pseudo-bash, this is what I would like to be able to do :

```
bash > config_virtual_file -virtualname = xyz.csv -newname = 'xyz ' + CURRENT_DATE + '.csv' 
xyz.csv virtual file created 
bash > psql

psql > copy (SELECT * from clients) TO xyz.csv
psql > go 
psql > \q

bash > ls *.csv
xyz 2013-12-16 13:15:20.csv
bash > ls -virtual_files
xyz.csv
```

Hoping this is clear.
I checked other postings and discovered symbolic links.
Unfortunately (for this particular case), symbolic links redirect input into other existing files or folders. I'm looking for a way for the incoming data to be directed into a new file.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Unix? Your path has backslashes, which suggests Windows, but the name looks more like a Unix name (`/home/yerleth/mydata`).

Comment: How often does the command execute?

Comment: 1. I'm on Ubuntu Linux bash. Don't worry about the slashes.

Comment: 2. I manually run the code every so often for testing and a robot on a remote site receives and deals with the CSV file. The robot won't accept a file that has the same name as a previous file. That's why each file needs a unique name. Timestamps would be OK. Once testing is done, the treatment will be less frequent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bash` to create the PostgreSQL script:

```
echo "COPY ... TO '$HOME/mydata$(date +%Y%m%d).csv';" > pgsql.script
```

and then feed the resulting file to the SQL command interpreter (`pgsql`?).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, thanks. I had thought about that but the COPY TO is just the tail end of a 200 line script and I was trying to avoid having to "echo ... >"  all that.

I believe that the notion of virtual files existed in the now defunct HP OS "MPE/iX" that I used to work with c.20 years ago. I'm sure I didn't invent the idea myself. I'm pretty new to bash and I imagined that such a useful function existed there too.

A "virtual file" functions like a printer only the OS has to output to a disk file and give that file a new name based on the config parms. 
The parms include the naming schema, using fixed text and/or variables : "serial", "randombetween", "UID", "timestamp" ...